# htaccess RewriteRule not working anymore

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Earlier today i got the following code working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1
```

Now I tried to extend the code by changing the last line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?p=$1&sub1=$2&sub3=$3
```

But now it doesnt work anymore, it just tries to direct me to the directory I request instead of the rewrite and then 404's because the dir ofcourse doesn't exist.

Also this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?p=$1&sub1=$2&sub3=$3
```

doesn't work.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance again :)

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess OR any other .htaccess in your system?

Comment: This rule cannot do external redirect unless you have some other rule OR your code doing it.

Comment: If you use `index.php` as a router (gets all requests, index.php decides what to do with it), then rybo's answer is probably the best solution. Remember that in per-directory context, such as .htaccess, the part matched by the regex never begins with a /. Trailing slashes are sometimes automatically stripped from urls if a certain directive isn't set, which would make your rule don't match. You can match the last slash with `/?` (zero or one slash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Then on index.php, you can use:

```
$p = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

You can then access $p[1], $p[2], etc.

Comment: Thanks! When trying so hard to make something out of htaccess code its the easy solutions that you forget.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `(.*)` probably takes your whole path, causing it to look for 3 slashes at the end so you would need lazy matching to avoid that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/ index.php?p=$1&sub1=$2&sub3=$3
```

Although personally I would not blindly accept all characters but do something like (depending on your exact needs...):

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/ index.php?p=$1&sub1=$2&sub3=$3
```

This would allow only word characters and the minus characters in your path names.